# Why does input tensor contain more dimensions than the shape of the input?

Tags: c++, interpreter, tensorflow-lite

I have converted a custom trained image segmentation TensorFlow model to TF Lite format and am now trying to run inference on the model using the CPP API.

I'm investigating the input and output tensors and was following the following [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/examples/minimal/minimal.cc) to do so.
The weird thing is that the shape of my input tensor is bigger than the images I need to feed to my model. The images have shape 480x640x3 but `dims->data` in the snippet below incorporates much more info than that (see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aZLt.png) of my console). How come?

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "tensorflow/lite/interpreter.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/kernels/register.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/model.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/optional_debug_tools.h"
#include <time.h>


using namespace tflite;
using namespace std;

#define TFLITE_MINIMAL_CHECK(x)                              \
  if (!(x)) {                                                \
    fprintf(stderr, "Error at %s:%d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__); \
    exit(1);                                                 \
  }

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "minimal <tflite model>\n");
    return 1;
  }
  const char* filename = argv[1];
  int startt, endd;
  startt = clock();

  // Load model
  // Load model
  std::unique_ptr<tflite::FlatBufferModel> model =
      tflite::FlatBufferModel::BuildFromFile(filename);
  TFLITE_MINIMAL_CHECK(model != nullptr);

  // Build the interpreter
  tflite::ops::builtin::BuiltinOpResolver resolver;
  std::unique_ptr<Interpreter> interpreter(new Interpreter());
  InterpreterBuilder builder(*model, resolver);
  std::cout << "allocating a number of threads" << std::endl;
  int numthreads=4;
  interpreter->SetNumThreads(numthreads);
  std::cout << "threads allocated" << std::endl;

  builder(&interpreter);
  TFLITE_MINIMAL_CHECK(interpreter != nullptr);
  endd = clock();

  // Allocate tensor buffers.
  TFLITE_MINIMAL_CHECK(interpreter->AllocateTensors() == kTfLiteOk);
  printf("=== Pre-invoke Interpreter State ===\n");
  tflite::PrintInterpreterState(interpreter.get());

  double time_taken = double(endd-startt)/double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
  std::cout << "a number of threads should be selected" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Time taken to load in the model in tflite using CPP API :" << fixed << time_taken << std::setprecision(5);
  std::cout << " sec " << std::endl;


  // Fill input buffers
  std::cout << "inputs : " << interpreter->inputs().size() << "\n";
  std::cout << "inputs(0) name : " << interpreter->GetInputName(0) << "\n";
  std::cout << "tensors size: " << interpreter->tensors_size() << "\n";
  std::cout << "nodes size: " << interpreter->nodes_size() << "\n";
  int startinput = clock();
  int input = interpreter->inputs()[0];
  std::cout << "input.1 : " << input <<"\n";
  const std::vector<int> inputs = interpreter->inputs();
  const std::vector<int> outputs = interpreter->outputs();
  std::cout << "number of inputs: " <<inputs.size() << "\n";
  std::cout << "number of outputs: " <<outputs.size() << "\n";

  TfLiteIntArray* dims = interpreter->tensor(input)->dims;
  int test0 = dims->data[0];
  int wanted_channels = dims->data[1];
  int wanted_height = dims->data[2];
  int wanted_width = dims->data[3];
  int test4 = dims->data[4];
  int test5 = dims->data[5];
  int test6 = dims->data[6];
  std::cout << "type of input tensor: " << interpreter->tensor(input)->type << std::endl;
  std::cout << "height, width, channels of input : " << wanted_height << " " << wanted_width << " "<< wanted_channels <<  " " << test0 << " " << test4 << " " << test5 << " " << test6 << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Can you use Netron to view your model and post its input / output here?
https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron

Comment: Yes! you can find the screenshot in this [link](https://imgur.com/njnVzO8)